# How can I store string from object as a variable?

Tags: php, string, variables, selector

I get this object in echo $output:

```
{
  "Key":"a-string-with-letters-and-numbers"
}
```

How can I store the string ("a-string-with-letters-and-numbers") as a variable, or can i echo this directly with selectors?

I need to store the string into this script:

```
options({
  key: "<?php echo $output ?>"
});
```

Comment: Show complete code from where you are getting this object

Comment: Something like this? $output= $yourObjectName->Key;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not an object in PHP, it is a JSON string that you need to decode to convert it in an php object or an array

```
 $json  = '{"Key":"a-string-with-letters-and-numbers"}';
 $object = json_decode($json);
 echo $object->key; // object

 $array = json_decode($json, true);
 echo $array['key']; // array
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *json_decode*

```
$output = json_decode('{
  "Key":"a-string-with-letters-and-numbers"
}');

echo $output->Key;
```

Comment: I don't know why Filip not accepts your answer. But i look your the first to answer his question

Answer (score 1):

you have an object in json format. Suppose you have your object in variable `$object`.
you can convert the object in to array by `$obj_to_arr = json_decode($object, true);`
now use the `key` of object to get its value from array like:
`$key_value = $obj_to_arr['key'];`
if you don't want to convert your object into array then you can also do it like:
`$my_object = json_decode($object);
$value = $my_object->key;`

Answer (score 1):

You can create dynamic variables in php.

${"required_string"}="required_string".
Then access that variable as like normal variable $required_string.
But '-' is not allowed in variable.

Hope this will help you.